# how to get nested xml tags in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a code to generate csv file from xml using XSL. I have to access a tag in one level up or two level. e.g i have to access `<value>` tag once and `<embeddeddata>` tag in loop

```
<root>
    <row>
        <data>
            <value>someValue  </value>
        </data>
        <dtl>
            <embeddeddata>
                <col1>col1 </col1>
            </embeddeddata>
            <embeddeddata>
                <col1>col2 </col1>
            </embeddeddata>
        </dtl>
    </row>
</root>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your XSLT file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try accessing the element by ../../ similar to the linux cd command to reach the element in the loop for

Comment: yes, ../../ I am able to access the elements. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try accessing elements in XLS file by ../../